# Output of PRINT statement inside stored procedure doesn't APPEAR IN CLIENT

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am running on Microsoft Sql Server 2012.
From Microsoft Sql Server Studio Management I ran the following code:

```
                use [TEST]
            GO

            DECLARE @return_value int

            EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ALBERT-TEST1]
            @dealId=N'1'

            SELECT 'Return Value'=@return_value
            GO



            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALBERT-TEST1]

            @dealId varchar(12)

            AS

            DECLARE @settleDateBool bit

            PRINT 'Margin Rate: '

            GO
```

I was hoping to see the print statement "Margin Rate" but I didn't see it.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Comment: These are informational messages; it depends on your client if there's any way to capture them. In .NET it's done by hooking up an event handler to `SqlConnection.InfoMessage`. In general it is a very bad idea to rely on these to communicate essential things back to the client; use output parameters or result sets instead (formatting/pretty-printing results is always the client's responsibility). Do not use the return value of a stored procedure for anything except a status code, as it only supports `INT` and is not nullable (defaulting to `0`).

Comment: Oh, and if your question was just "where do I see these in *Management Studio*" (I may have been overthinking things): there's a separate "Messages" tab next to the tab with results that carries these. You can also switch the output to "output to text" instead of "output to grid" to get the messages inline. Again, though, even for SSMS it's a bad idea to rely on `PRINT` for basically anything other than crude debugging.

Comment: Another possibility is that the example code posted tries to invoke the stored procedure before the stored procedure gets created.